# WKWebView not loading HTML content before scripts load

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

I have a simple view controller that loads an html file hosted locally on my machine:

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webView = WKWebView()

        ...

        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8002/myendpoint")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

}
```

The html loaded is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    Hello World!

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/js/file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the content ("Hello World!") isn't rendering until the script is loaded (which takes around 3 seconds). If I comment out the script tag, it loads immediately.

With the script tag, it works fine on Android (content loads immediately as it should).

My understanding is the HTML should happen sequentially so "Hello World!" should be rendered before loading the script tag (the way it works on Android).

**Is there a way to force the content to be loaded in order on `WKWebView`?** I found [suppressesIncrementalRendering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1395663-suppressesincrementalrendering), but the default is already `false`, and changing or explicitly setting it doesn't seem to help.

I also already tried `async` and `defer` on the script tag, but they don't help either.

Comment: Did you try `<script async src="/path...`?

Comment: @KoshVery, yes forgot to mention - `async` and `defer` don't help either.

Comment: do u resolve? i met the same problem